# Unusual example of Compton Scattering (+Four-momentum approach, +nonrelativistic)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, scattering

An electron of kinetic energy $k=100 keV$ (first note, doesn't this mean that its energy is much lower than $0.511 MeV$, and thus that it is a nonrelativistic electron we are dealing with?), collides with a photon of wavelength $\lambda = 0.003 nm$ head-on.

I imagined the electron moving from left to right on the horizontal x-axis, colliding with the photon and then heading "downwards", towards the negative y-axis, at an angle $\phi$ in relation to the x-axis (I thought of $\phi$ as the acute angle).
The photon recoils "backwards" (to the right), at an angle $\theta$ in relation to the x-axis (again, I deemed $\theta$ as being the acute angle).

**First question** is:

When expressing the four-momenta, do I have to consider the ordinary momenta's directions?
For example, if I take the electron's direction (to the right) as the positive one, do I have to write the photon's left-facing initial momentum as a negative component in its four-momentum, i.e. $P_γ=(E_γ, -p_γc, 0, 0)$?

Then, of course, arises the **most important problem**:

Since the electron's initial four-momentum will ***not*** be of the form $(mc^2,0,0,0)$, but rather $P_e=(E_e,p_ec,0,0)$, with $E_e=mc^2+K$ (nonrelativistic) or $E_e=\sqrt{(m^2c^4+p^2c^2)}$ (relativistic), much more complex equations occur from the conservation of four-momentum (i.e. $P_e+P_γ=P_e'+P_γ'$), and the familiar equation for the wavelength of the occurring photon can not be extracted. Any thoughts?

I have been working on this Compton scattering example for days, and would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Four momentum has units of momentum, so the four momentum of the initial photon is:

$$ q_{\mu} = (E_{\gamma}/c, 0,0,-E_{\gamma}/c) $$

(Note: the beam axis is always $z$, $x$ is the scattering plane for unpolarized beams, and $y$ is out-of-plane, but that doesn't matter for 2 body unpolarized reactions).

Also, depending on your field, it is mostly traditional to use $k_{\mu}, q_{\mu}, p_{\mu}$ for leptons, photons, hadron, respectively.

It's also easier to set $c=1$ and put factors in at the end, if needed. So for the electron:

$$ E = m_e + T $$

(note that $T$ is the traditional variable for kinetic energy in SR kinematic problems), then:

$$ k = \sqrt{(E^2 - m_e^2)} $$
$$ k = \sqrt{\big((m_e+T)^2 - m_e^2)\big)}$$
$$ k = \sqrt{\big((m_e^2 + T^2 + 2m_eT - m_e^2)\big)}$$
$$ k = \sqrt{T(2m_e+T)} \approx 335\,{\rm keV}$$
The photon, electron and total 4 momenta are:

$$ q_{\mu} = (E_{\gamma}, 0,0,-E_{\gamma}) $$
$$ k_{\mu} = (m_e+T, 0,0, k) $$
$$ p_{\mu} = (E_{\gamma} + m_e + T, 0, 0, m_e+T-E_{\gamma} $$

Since we all have memorized $\hbar c=197\,{\rm  MeV\cdot fm}$, $E_{\gamma} = 66\,{\rm keV}$:

$$ p_0 = 677\, {\rm keV} $$
$$ p_z = 545\, {\rm keV} $$

Q1: yes, you need to consider the direction of 3 momenta to deal with 4-momenta.

Q2: there is no 2nd question, but it is implied by *"first question"*.

Regarding angle, usually theta is the polar angle defined relative to the positive $z$ direction, but it's too late to fix that. I assumed the electron defined the lab coordinates, but that's backwards.

Now since I have personally scattered 512 nm photons head-on off of 28 GeV positrons, I can get behind the photon defining the coordinates.

So the photon scatters $\theta$, and the electron goes to $\phi$. Note, we define $x$ to be the scattering plane, because there is ZERO information in the out-of-plane variables.

The electron's 4-momenta is:

$$ k_{\mu}' = (E', k'\sin{\theta}, 0, k'\cos{\theta}) $$

$$
k_{\mu}' = \frac{m_e}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}(1, \beta\sin\theta, 0, \beta\cos\theta)$$

where the 2nd form uses $E'^2 = k'^2 + m_e^2$.

The photon has four momenta:

$$ q'_{\mu} = ||q'||(1, \sin{\phi}, 0, \cos{\phi}) $$

So you can take it from there, since:

$$ q'_0 + k'_0 = p_0 $$
$$ q'_1 + k'_1 = p_1 $$
$$ q'_2 + k'_2 = p_2 $$
$$ q'_3 + k'_3 = p_3 $$

is 4-equations for $\beta, ||q'||, \theta, \phi$

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. With all due appreciation, I feel your approach perplexed the problem, for it changed its "language" significantly. I was thinking of a more introductory-quantum-mechanics approach, based on this typical Compton example solved by Harvard.  (https://www.physics.harvard.edu/files/sol69.pdf), where using four-momenta in this manner (and using simply x,y, Pe, Pγ, etc) much simplifies the conventional approach of separate equations for conservation of energy, conservation of momentum in x-axis and in y-axis.

Comment: well I did use 4 momenta, so feel free to change the variable names as needed. You can solve it with $\beta$ or $\vec p'$, it's that the former automatically enforces $E'^2=m^2+p^2$ via $(\gamma m)^2=m^2+(\gamma \beta m)^2$, that's relativity 101. Wavelength doesn't transform nicely, so for the photon I use $|\vec q|=\hbar c/(\lambda/(2\pi)) = hc/\lambda$ with $\hbar =c=1$. Regarding axis names, that doesn't matter, but _everyone_ does $p_{\mu} = (E, p_T, 0, p_L)$ where T (L) is transverse (longitudinal). Also $P=cp_{\mu}$ is not standard: $p_{\mu}=(E/c, \vec p)$ is.

Comment: I see... In any case, thank you!